# Tabs/Tab not working on initial load in react-materialize

Tags: reactjs, tabs, materialize

I have created a react component using Tabs, It is not working on initial load but works once i reload the page.

My render function is as below

```
<Tabs className='tab-demo z-depth-1'>
   <Tab title="Components" active>
      <form className="col s12">
         <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field col s5">
               <input id="file_search" type="text" className="validate" />
               <label htmlFor="file_search">Search</label>
            </div>
            <div style={styles.restorecomp}>
               <span className="btn indigo darken-4 selectdrop" onClick={this.open}><i className="material-icons left">restore</i> Restore a Component</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <span className="btn indigo darken-4 selectdrop" onClick={this.save} ><i className="material-icons left">save</i> Save</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
      <table className="highlight centered" id="files">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="comp"> Name</th>
               <th data-field="type">Type</th>
               <th data-field="version">Version</th>
               <th data-field="user">Data Source</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </Tab>
   <Tab title="Data Sources">
      <form className="col s12">
         <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field col s5">
               <input id="ds_search" type="text" className="validate" />
               <label htmlFor="ds_search">Search</label>
            </div>
            <div style={styles.restorecomp}>
               <span className="btn indigo darken-4 selectdrop" onClick={this.dsopen}><i className="material-icons left">restore</i> Restore DataSource</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <span className="btn indigo darken-4 selectdrop" onClick={this.save}><i className="material-icons left">save</i> Save</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
      <table className="highlight centered" id="ds">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="comp"> Alias</th>
               <th data-field="tname"> Name</th>
               <th data-field="connection">Connection</th>
               <th data-field="type">Type</th>
               <th data-field="version">Version</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </Tab>
   <Tab title="Files">
      <form className="col s12">
         <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field col s5">
               <input id="fv_search" type="text" className="validate" />
               <label htmlFor="fv_search">Search</label>
            </div>
            <div style={styles.restorecomp}>
               <span className="btn indigo darken-4 selectdrop" onClick={this.fileopen}><i className="material-icons left">restore</i> Restore a File</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <span className="btn indigo darken-4 selectdrop" onClick={this.save}><i className="material-icons left">save</i> Save</span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
      <table className="highlight centered" id="fv">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th data-field="comp">Name</th>
               <th data-field="type">Path</th>
               <th data-field="version">Version</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Tabs not loaded when i load the component using react router, But it get loaded perfectly if i refresh the page manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the issue id #196 in react-materialize github repo.

This issue has been fixed in the version 0.17.7

https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/196